# Sending a request to Google Vision API

Tags: java, google-cloud-vision

I want to send a json object while by using the http POST method to the Google Vision API. I am using the following code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<API-KEY>"); 
HttpsURLConnection http = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
http.setDoOutput(true);
http.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
http.connect();

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(http.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(request.toString());
Log.v("JSON",request.toString());
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

I getting a bad request error. Need help with this. The format of my json object (request) is as follows:

```
{"imageContext":"",
 "requests":"
    {"image":
        {"content":"..."},
    "features":
        {"type":"WEB DETECTION"}
        {"maxResults":10}
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the details of the error that you get? Is there extended error information in the response? Are you sure you have authenticated properly? Oh, and your JSON is not correctly formatted, although that might be a cut-and-paste error. Please post the *exact* JSON. And shouldn't `features` be an array?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#Feature), `features` should be an array like this:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": "..."
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "WEB_DETECTION",
          "maxResults": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

See also [this page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web).

Answer (score 0):

I am constructing my json object as follows: Here variable encoded contains the 64 bit encoded string of the image

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject();

//image object
JSONObject i = new JSONObject();
i.put("content",encoded);

//feature object
JSONObject features = new JSONObject();
List<JSONObject> featureList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject f = new JSONObject();
f.put("type","WEB_DETECTION");
f.put("maxResults",10);
featureList.add(f);

 List<JSONObject> requestList = new ArrayList<>();
 JSONObject r = new JSONObject();
 r.put("image",i);
 r.put("features",featureList);
 requestList.add(r);

 //final json object
 request.put("imageContext","");
 request.put("requests",requestList);
```